# What abilities does a high rep'd user doesn't have that a mod has?

Tags: discussion, moderation

What abilities do a moderator have more than, lets say a 10k or 20k rep'd user?

Comment: Sekret powahs! :)

Comment: Shadow cloaks and Phaser guns!

Comment: The diamond! Don't forget the diamond!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From an FAQ post on Meta.SO:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75192/151385)

> - They have access to all the abilities of 10k users regardless of their reputation.
> - Their votes are binding. Any place we have voting — close, open, delete, undelete, offensive, migration, etc — that vote will reach the
>     threshold and take effect immediately if a single diamond moderator
>     casts a vote.
> - They can [lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post)
>     posts. Locked posts cannot be voted on, commented, or changed in any
>     way.
> - They can [protect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/)
>     questions. Protected questions only allow answers by users with more
>     than 10 reputation.
> - They can see more data in the system, including vote statistics (but not ‘who voted for this post’) and user profile information.
> - They can view all deleted posts on an individual user's profile.
> - They can place users in timed suspension, and delete users if necessary.
> - They can perform large-scale maintenance actions such as merging questions and tags, tag synonym approvals, unbounded question
>     migration, and so forth.
> - They can convert a post into Community Wiki status, or convert an answer into a comment.

Comment: Apparently [protecting questions](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/protect-questions) is a 15K thing now